# Measuring time spent while sending data to client?

Tags: c#, sockets, time, stopwatch

I have tried measuring time for socket send time:

```
stopWatch.Start();
socket.Send(buffer);
socket.Close();
stopWatch.Stop();
```

But ~95% of the times, stopwatch returns time that is <1second (with 5mb and bigger buffer).
After running `socket.send()` within .5-1 milliseconds is says that file was send, even thou user is still downloading. How could I change my code so correct upload time will be returned?
Thank you.

Comment: That measures the time required for the data to go from your app to the webserver, which is a local transfer. You'd have to watch for when the outgoing socket closes which would most likely be when the transfer's complete.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that Marc might be indeed correct.  Of course your code is not enough to provide any guidence one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

socket.Send(buffer);
socket.Close();

TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);
double msec = span.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

MarcB seems to be correct. On top of that, make sure to get more precision from your stopwatch e.g.

```
double seconds = (double)stopWatch.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
```